# J# runtime needed in visual studio 2010 setup project

Tags: .net, windows-installer, j#

I have some code I needed to merge into my project where some developers had used the J# runtime to handle a few things. The application is running, but now I am trying to build an installer. I've tried to determine how to add the J# merge module to the setup project but can not find this merge module anywhere. I have downloaded the vjredist64.exe file and installed it, but no options are available in the prerequisites section of the setup project for J# and no merge modules for J# (VJSharpRedist_x86.msm) were added to my system that I can find (I do see prerequisites for F# and C++ runtimes available). The project is set to run on the 3.5 Framework because of the J# requirements. I've taken a look at all of the Microsoft documentation I could find and have gone through all the steps, but I feel I am missing something, the project was originally for the 4.0 framework but was changed to 3.5 due to the J# requirements. Anyone have any thoughts? If I could be more detailed in my explanation please let me know. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't exist. The only thing that exists is in VS 2005 there is a bootstrapper module for J#. But it is for the old version of J# and that is 32-bit only. You have to run the J# setup .exe program to install.

BTW - you can run on .NET 4.0. Just follow the instructions at [Calling J# code from .NET 4.0](http://blogs.windwardreports.com/davidt/2011/02/calling-j-code-from-net-40.html).